# Scala library in build path doesn't expose its version (Android App Dev)

Tags: android, eclipse, scala, eclipse-plugin, scala-ide

I am receiving the following error when I add android-scala.jar to the build path of my android application: The scala library found in the build path doesn't expose its version.  Please replace the scala library with the scala container or a valid scala library jar.  Does anyone have any idea what maybe causing this or a potential solution to this problem??  Let me know if more information is helpful; however, I cannot even get the emulator to launch with the current error.

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/scala-ide-user/browse_thread/thread/600cc482bb310c03

Comment: I already stumbled upon this through a google search; however, I do not understand the solution that they present.  Could you detail this better for me?  I have used this file before in a previous version of eclipse, and did not have to go through the previous steps specified.  Is there an easy way to name the file (such that it conforms to the compilers expectations?).

Answer (score 1):

The library needs to be called scala-library.jar, and it has to contain the original library.properties file from the standard Scala library jar.

Comment: I do not believe this to be the case as I've used the file entitled android-scala.jar before in the build path.  Everything was completely functional until I ported this onto my new computer.  Moreover, I've checked my configuration settings on the old box and it matches that of the new.

Comment: You probably have a newer version of the Scala plugin on your new computer. There is a new classpath validator that was added around 3 weeks ago.

Comment: It would be nice if Scala IDE let this behavior be overridden.  The same problem occurs with OSGi applications what have an OSGi enabled scala-library JAR that isn't named scala-library.jar.